# Database Query with EF Core in 2.1

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have just created a brand new core MVC app with identity.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to get entity framework to do a database query.

I have an ApplicationDBContext

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}
```

whenever I try to use it it just tells me i have no options sent.

I'm trying to run a query on my UserAddresses table and have changed my ASPNetUsers table to Users.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Update the ApplicationUser Table to Users and change primary column to UserId
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Users");
            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        });
    }

    public DbSet<UserAddress> UserAddresses { get; set; }
```

This is the entire Class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Update the ApplicationUser Table to Users and change primary column to UserId
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Users");
            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        });
    }

    public DbSet<UserAddress> UserAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

How do I connect to the DBContext to run queries using EF

Update

I was able to get it by passing my `_context` into the controller through a constructor like this

```
private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you change the implement from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` to just `DbContext`?

Comment: What query did you want to run? Share us related code, and where did you get this error. I only see the configuration, but did not find how you call `_context `.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var user = await context.UserAddresses.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == UserId);

    return user;
}
```

add an empty constructor:

```
public ApplicationDbContext() {}
```

Comment: InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Comment: This is in my configure services `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`

Comment: Can you post your `Startup.cs` and `Program.cs` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private ApplicationDbContext _context;
public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

// this will get the userId of currently loggedIn user
userId = User.Identity.GetUserId()

// this line get all the address of loggedIn user from UserAddresses table
_context.UserAddresses.Where(a => a.UserId == userId).ToList();
```

You cal also get single address, first address or last address etc.

> Configuration in Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```